# When to stop querying paypal api's for payment status?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-adaptive-payments

Using the parallel payments paypal api.  If user 1 makes a payment to user 2, I make a check using the api to make sure paypal returns the payment details as COMPLETED.

How long does paypal keep that COMPLETED payment record?  Do they keep it indefinitely, or do they delete it after a while?  I ask because I am at the stage of development where I need to decide if I should rely on paypal keeping that record indefinitely, or if I should create a record on my server that the payment has been completed, or if I should always check if the payment has been marked as COMPLETED by querying paypal?

The only reason why I "want" to check via paypal, is if the payment is ever returned to user1 as REFUNDED or PARITALLY_REFUNDED when paypal is queried using their apis.  I would want to act accordingly in such situations.

It's not too much of an issue if the status is REFUNDED or PARTIALLY_REFUNDED as apparently people can't get refunds if they don't open a case with paypal before 45 days are up.  I am more concerned about the REVERSED status, which can apparently happen any time, even after 45 days which is beyond paypal's control, as it is done by the credit card companies, if the user pays by credit card...

Comment: I thought PayPal sends to your IPN request that confirm it is completed. You do not need to query it. Just wait when PP does it.

Comment: @SergeyRomanov, the reason why I am querying for the status is to ensure the user doesn't double pay for example accidentally, which will mean more work for me in the long run.  If I can stop them from double paying right from the start, then I will have to do less work letter hopefully when people ring me up or email me that they accidentally double payed etc.

Comment: Here is how I do it usually. I create order before send to paypal. And I pass to PP the order ID. SO when user try again I can either load the same  order if it is still unpaid or inform that this may be a second attempt depending on order creation date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `PaymentDetails` request I was able to pull my oldest Adaptive Payment transaction, which was over 60 days old and had no problems pulling it up using the `transactionId` field. It should be able to pull up payments as long as they are listed in the PayPal account (currently forever.)

This will work using the `payKey` field also if you are storing that instead of `transactionId`, however the `transactionId` is displayed in your PayPal account and is sent with IPN responses.